# Python csv new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have blank csv (created with Python) and I want to add for example, 5 columns.

I have:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(['this', 'is', 'not', '5', 'columns'])
```

But if I open this file in Excel output is: *this,is,not,5,columns* all in first column.

Desired output is that each word will be in **separate column**.

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: For starters, you locally overwrite the module name by calling your open file `csv`. Your code cannot be executed. Change that `csv` to something else. Other than that, I could not reproduce your problem. Everything works as expected.

Comment: If I open this file in Excel all text is in first column.

Comment: Are you sure your code is the entire [mre]? I ran your code _verbatim_, and I have five columns in Excel https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x6XN.png

Comment: I also have five columns in Excel. This may have more to do with the version of Excel you are using or the file opening settings in Excel. The python code generates a comma-separated file as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In csv files, columns can be separated by commas or semicolons. In your case, you have to choose manually choose comma as the separator. Go to Excel => data => open from text file or csv and choose your file and in delimiter choose comma

[image]